# How can I make Sublime Text 2 recognize the pipe as a bracket

Tags: sublime-text-2

The reason I want this is so I can use the move_to brackets command in a block argument list.

Take:

```
hash.each_pair do |key, value|
    puts "K:#{key} V:#{value}"
end
```

I want to be able to have ST2 recognize the `|key, value|` area as a bracket block.

Comment: If I have `|key, value|key2, value2|key3, value3|`, where should it jump to from the first one? I think the problem is that there is no way to determine nesting from pipes like you can braces/brackets (at least not without much more intensive syntax parsing).

Comment: @DarthAndroid you can't have nested pipes in the context of ruby.  You *may* be able to do a line continuation to put the starting-ending pipes on different lines, but I have never seen that and would be fine if it didn't support that.